# ¿Como Crear Metodo Que genere Acceso Directo de un Archivo Especifico C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de crear un metodo en C# que al pasarle la ruta de un archivo seleccionado este pueda crear un acceso directo de dicho archivo en el escritorio, este es el metodo:

```
private void CrearAccesoD(string FilePath)
        {
            string EscritorioDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
            
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(EscritorioDir + "\\NombreArchivo"))
            {
              
                writer.WriteLine("[AccesoDirecto]");
                writer.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + FilePath);
                writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
                string icon = FilePath.Replace('\\', '/');
                writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
```

El inconveniente aqui es que en vez de crear un acceso directo del archivo seleccionado, me esta creando un acceso directo del ejecutable del mismo proyecto. No comprendo que estoy realizando mal. Agradeceria apoyo para aclarecer donde estoy fallando.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolver utilizando este metodo:

```
 private void CrearAccesoD(string FilePath)
        {
    
                object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";

                WshShell shell = new WshShell();

                string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\CuadreATM.lnk";

                IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);

                shortcut.TargetPath = app;
                shortcut.Save();

        }
```

Para esto deben importar a su proyecto la libreria:

```
Using Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary;
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien con el mismo tema :)